# How to Pump Out Custom dialog after My Image Spin stops

Tags: java, android

I have a custom dialog that I want to show on a touch event after and animation finishes. My animation completes, but the dialog isn't showing. here is the method that is suppose to call the dialog.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
            {
                ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.animatedImage);
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog (Player3AccessActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

                    switch(event.getAction())
                        {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            start =1000;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            start= start +250;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Random random=new Random();
                            int toDegrees= random.nextInt(start +1000);


                            iv.animate()
                            .rotation(toDegrees)
                            .setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator())
                            .setDuration(1000);
                            dialog.show();
                            break;


                        }

                    return(true);

            }
```

Comment: How to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Edit now that i understand better:

If you're calling this from your Main Activity then I think you need to change to: `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);` or `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());`

I'm also not familiar with `return(true);` at the end, I think that should be `return true;`

edit again:

So it should look something like this

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 

    ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.animatedImage); 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {

        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            start =1000;
            return true;

        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            start= start +250;
            return true;

        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Random random=new Random();
            int toDegrees= random.nextInt(start +1000);
            iv.animate()
            .rotation(toDegrees)
            .setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(1000);

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog (this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.show();

            return true;

        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I already create Custom Dialog for that. but Dialog not show after bottle stop.